# Creating a SqlDbConnection class in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, class

I'm trying to create a SqlDbConnection class file for my application. And I want use this connection class to connect to the database whenever it requires. Till now what I have for the class code is:

```
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace SqlTesting
{
public class SqlDbConnection
{
    private SqlConnection con;
    public SqlCommand cmd;
    private SqlDataAdapter sda;
    private DataTable dt;

    public SqlDbConnection()
    {
        con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DB_SQL;Integrated Security=SSPI;");
        con.Open();
    }

    public void SqlQuery(string querytext)
    {
        cmd = new SqlCommand(querytext, con);
    }

    public DataTable QueryEx()
    {
        sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }

    public void NonQueryEx()
    {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
}
```

I guess that I need to call the DbConnection.Dispose Method, so it will close and dispose of the SqlConnection. Now I'm bit confused with how I should use the Dispose() method on my SqlDbConnection class file. So any related guideline would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Keeping a `SqlConnection` around for longer than required is generally a bad idea, IMO. Also note that your class doesn't implement `IDisposable`, which it definitely should *if* you keep your class around. I'd suggest not doing so though...

Comment: con.Close() Dispose the connection

Comment: What's the actual question? It look to me you are trying to create a utility class of some kind, but honestly, there is not much value added in this. The connection string is taken care of, and logic to create a data table from the results of a query. But that's about it.

Comment: I agree with Jon Skeet - you should not keep a SqlConnection open. Consider to add convenience methods using extensions: public DataTable QueryEx(this SqlConnection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always important to call Dispose/Close on all Objects that implement iDisposable.
And of course that means SqlDBConnection.

Disposable Resources

Common disposable resources include the following:

```
 1.Database-related
    classes: SqlConnection, SqlDataReader, and SqlTransaction.
 2. File-based classes: FileStream and BinaryWriter. Stream-based
    classes: StreamReader, TextReader, TextWriter, BinaryReader, and
    TextWriter. 
 3. Network-based classes: Socket, UdpClient, and TcpClient.
```

A great place to check out for guidelines is Microsoft Best Practice:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647790.aspx#scalenetchapt05_topic11

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to use  `SqlDbConnection : IDisposable`

After use the above

```
       public void Dispose()
        {
            con.Close();                
            cmd.Dispose();
        }
```

Comment: Thx for suggestion i will remove one of them.